# Can fireflies species be identified with their wavelength?

Tags: entomology, methods

I was wondering if we could ID male fireflies using their wavelength? A bit like how we use UV light to ID species of scorpions.

Comment: This might be a bit broad; I don't know. There are many species of fireflies, with different flashing patterns and intensities; some male fireflies don't even bioluminesce. Though the luciferin may be slightly different among species, I would doubt (but have no evidence) that it is different among sexes of the same species. It's much easier to tell which are males by their location and flash patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes it should be possible, but probably not for all species and as @anongoodnurse said there are probably easier methods of species-identification.

*Elaboration:*
I know (but could not find a reference) that there are currently hyperspectral cameras that are able to capture bandwidths as small as 2 nm.

And there are differences in the emission spectrum of fireflies.
Firefly luciferase bioluminescence color can vary between yellow-green (λmax = 550 nm) to red (λmax = 620). ( https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2801227 ) There are currently several different mechanisms describing how the structure of luciferase affects the emission spectrum of the photon and effectively the color of light emitted. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferase)

However, it is likely that there are closely related species of firefly that have no (or very small) differences in emission spectrum. These will not be identifyable with spectral imaging.

Comment: Do you think we could ID individual in one species using wavelength ? Putting a set-up of those camera and then use Capture-recapture model to estimate population size ?

Comment: @NicoCoallier I don't know but I doubt that the spectral differences within a apecies are large enough. But there is only one way to find out...

Comment: very interesting stuff